# How can I find out what my 'On-Premises Authority' url is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, active-directory, adfs

I'm setting up a new .NET MVC project and want to use my local ADFS for managing users. I know the IP address of the machine my ADFS is running on and have tried using that for the 'On-Premises Authority' URL, but I got an message stating that it was incorrect.

Is there a command I can run to find the address/url that I should be using for this field?

For reference, this is the menu box I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You insert the metadata address of your ADFS e.g.

```
https://some-server/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml
```

Comment: Where can this URL be found?  Is this URL used for everyone using ADFS?

Comment: Yes - it's the ADFS metadata address used by anyone who wants to add either Claims Providers or Relying Parties.

Comment: Still works. Just tried it on my server. Maybe there's something wrong with your network - firewall? Does it work from a browser?

Answer (score 1):

This must be provided by your IT-Team.

Usually it is:

`https://YOUR-ADFS-SERVER/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`